# Error while creating an X509 certificate with extensions in PyASN1

Tags: python, x509certificate, asn.1, pyasn1

I'm trying to create a X509v3 certificate and encode it in DER and save it into a file. I'm using PyASN1 0.1.7 and Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.

The code can be summarized as this:

```
tbs = rfc2459.TBSCertificate()
tbs.setComponentByName('XYZ', xyz)  # other non-problematic certificate fields
....
subjaltname = rfc2459.SubjectAltName()
subjaltname.setComponentByPosition(0, fc2459.GeneralName().setComponentByName('dNSName', 'domain.com'))
extension = rfc2459.Extension()
extension.setComponentByName('extnID', rfc2459.id_ce_subjectAltName)
extension.setComponentByName('critical', univ.Boolean(False))
extension.setComponentByName('extnValue', univ.OctetString(der_encoder.encode(subjaltname)))
extensions = rfc2459.Extensions()
extensions.setComponentByPosition(0, extension)
tbs.setComponentByName('extensions', extensions.subtype(explicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 3)))
cert = rfc2459.Certificate()
cert.setComponentByName('tbsCertificate', tbs)
```

When I try to encode `cert` object with DER encoder, I get this error:

```
pyasn1.type.error.ValueConstraintError: ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueSizeConstraint(1, 64)) failed at: "ValueSizeConstraint(1, 64) failed at: "Extensions()""
```

Any suggestions on the problematic part of code would be appreciated.

P.S. if anyone has a working sample code on how to create a X509v3 certificate with extensions using PyASN1, I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that when you make a subtype of Extensions object here:

```
tbs.setComponentByName('extensions',extensions.subtype(explicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 3)))
```

it loses its initial value. You could either try adding *cloneValueFlag=True* to .subtype() to force it doing a deep copy, or better do subtyping prior to initialization:

```
extensions = rfc2459.Extensions().subtype(explicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 3))
extensions.setComponentByPosition(0, extension)
tbs.setComponentByName('extensions', extensions)
```

Also enabling pyasn1 debugging may be helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. But now the certificate containing the extension is generated but openssl can't parse it. I've updated the question

Comment: Nevermind. I corrected the code by analyzing another certificate using `dumpasn1`. Works perfectly now. Thanks again for the library and helping out.

Comment: @sharklaser I'd love to see your final solution, I'm having similar problems.